# Does MAGMA use a standard p-modular system?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, magma-cas

I'd like to ask the following question:

> Are the Brauer character values of kG-modules (where k and G are finite) in MAGMA computed with respect to the standard p-modular system described in the book of Lux and Pahlings* (chapter 4 in Representations of Groups: A computational Approach)?

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**

*See pages 305-307 of https://books.google.de/books?id=VSZIBpYGwSMC&pg=PA315&lpg=PA315&dq=lux+pahlings+bruaer+characters&source=bl&ots=tjiXv1MYLC&sig=ACfU3U0HfCxHlCErPnMEnHRpxtwSEUccGw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif6uXzsc7iAhXB_KQKHX1cDWcQ6AEwDXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=lux%20pahlings%20bruaer%20characters&f=false

There, a bold $\mathbf{\zeta}_m$ denotes the complex number $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m}}$. Often, $m=p^n-1$.

Comment: also on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333175/does-magma-use-a-standard-p-modular-system

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: Thank you very much for the comment and for your answer on MO. Feel free to answer my question here as well, if you like.